# Can't seem to use optional foreign key relationships when creating new object using Django+AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm using AngularJS on the front-end with Django managing the backend and API along with the Django REST framework package. I have a Project model which belongs to User and has many (optional) Intervals and Statements. I need to be able to create a 'blank' project and add any intervals/statements later, but I'm hitting a validation error when creating the project. Below are the relevant code sections.

Django model code (simplified):

```
class Project(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='projects', on_delete='models.CASCADE')
  project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Statement(models.Model):
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='statements', on_delete='models.CASCADE', null=True, blank=True)

class Interval(models.Model):
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='intervals', on_delete='models.CASCADE', null=True, blank=True)
```

Django view code (simplified):

```
class ProjectList(APIView):
  def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = ProjectSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Angular controller code (simplified):

```
$scope.createProject = function(){
  var projectData = {
    "user": $scope.user.id,
    "project_name": $scope.newProject.project_name
  };
  apiSrv.request('POST', 'projects', projectData,
    function(data){},
    function(err){}
  );
};
```

Angular service code (simplified):

```
apiSrv.request = function(method, url, args, successFn, errorFn){
  return $http({
    method: method,
    url: '/api/' + url + ".json",
    data: JSON.stringify(args)
  }).success(successFn);
};
```

Server response:

```
{"intervals":["This field is required."],"statements":["This field is required."]}
```

Am I missing something here? I should be able to create a project without a statement or interval, but I'm not able to. Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: Added Relevant section from ProjectSerializer

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  intervals = IntervalSerializer(many=True)
  statements = StatementSerializer(many=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = (
              'id',
              'project_name',
              [removed extraneous project fields]
              'user',
              'intervals',
              'statements'
              )
```

Comment: Do you mind showing the ProjectSerializer?

Comment: My guess would be that 'intervals' and 'statements' are specified on the serializer, and not set as read_only=True.

Comment: @PieterHamman Yep, adding 'read_only=True' fixed it. Add that as an answer and I'll accept it once SO allows me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the read_only attribute on the 'interval' and 'statements' fields

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    intervals = IntervalSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    statements = StatementSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Project
       fields = ('id', 'project_name', 'user', 'intervals','statements')
```

or you can specify the read_only fields like this,

```
class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = ('id', 'project_name', 'user', 'intervals','statements')
    read_only_fields = ('intervals','statements')
```